# Broken Extremal.

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Consider the Functional $$J(y)=\int_0^2(1-y’^2)^2dx$$ defined on $$\{y\in C[0,2]\mid \text{y is piecewise $C^1$ and $y(0)=y(2)=0$}\}$$ Let $y_e$ be a minimizer of the above functional. Then $y_e$ has

$1.$ A unique corner point.

$2.$ Two corner point .

$3.$ More than two corner points.

$4.$ No corner point.

As I applied Euler equation with Weierstrass-Erdmann conditions, I got corner point $c$ with $y’(c-0)=1$ and $y’(c+0)=-1$ or $y’(c-0)=-1$ and $y’(c+0)=1$ . So according to this there can be many corner points by shifting  and making slopes 1 and -1 in left or right accordingly, like

$
y(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    x & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{4} \\
    -(x-\frac{1}{2})& \text{if } \frac{1}{4}\leq x  \leq  \frac{5}{4} \\
    x-2& \text{if } \frac{5}{4} \leq  x \leq 2\\
\end{cases}
$

But answer is given option $1$ i.e. unique corner. According to me  any zig-zag curve consisting of segments of slopes +1 and -1 and joining the two end-points would work. Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: @Gonçalo so can I say that there can be more than one corners?